# What is the purpose of port 19333 for SeaweedFS?

Tags: port, grpc, heartbeat, seaweedfs

I have this error:

```
I0929 12:58:57.623373 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:43 checkWithMaster 172.20.16.35:19333: get master 172.20.16.35:19333 configuration: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.20.16.35:29333: connect: connection refused"
```

Started SeaweedFS with:

```
./weed server -dir="./data"
```

version is 3.29 on RedHat 8.

Is port 19333 used for gRPC calls? For hearth beat? Can I turn this OFF? How?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2):

"Is port 19333 used for gRPC calls? For hearth beat? Can I turn this OFF?"
Yes. Yes. No.